# Mint cinnamon installation error

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I am running `Mint Cinnamon` on my 32-bit PC.

As I opened `Virtual Box` and selected `Start Mint Cinnamon` option it loaded for some time then a blank screen appeared.

To fix this I pressed `Ctrl + Alt + F1` The `tty1` login page  appeared.

I typed default username mint and password is nothing. So now a terminal window appeared.

I typed `sudo bash` and then entered command `startx` It processed it for some time then again a blank screen appeared. Nothing is happening further.

What should I do?

Comment: Are there any messages left behind after `startx`?

Comment: Yup ............

Comment: But no errors..

Comment: Does switching on/off the virtualbox 3D acceleration make a difference for you?

Comment: Nope nothing same is happening